# Maximal minimum for a sum of two (or more) cosines

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

Please prove (or disprove, and give the correct answer):

$$2 =\mathrm{argmax}_{r\geq 1}\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\left[\cos\left(x\right)+\cos\left(rx\right)\right]
 $$

In other words, find $r \geq 1$, for which the minimum (over $x$) of $\cos(x)+\cos(rx)$ is the largest. Or rather, prove that this $r$ is 2.

Background: I'm getting this result from a numerical scan

[image]

Also, it makes sense intuitively, since by drawing two cosines and trying to align them, this seems like a good configuration to get a high minimum

[image]

However, I cannot find a way to prove this. You can also easily show that the required points are not saddle points of the function $f(x,r)=\cos(x)+\cos(rx)$ (the only extremum points are on $x=\pi k$, $r$ integer, and they are all maxima), and instead they must occur for the values of $r$ for which you get two equal global minima. This sounds as a very strange coincidence in the general case. That's why I feel like there has to be some simple symmetry argument that can solve this. Am I missing something obvious (or not so obvious)?

Bonus question:

$$?=\mathrm{argmax}_{\bf r\in \mathbb{R}^N_+}\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N \cos\left(r_i x\right)\right]$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this even true? Consider any fixed $r$. If you fix $x = \pi$, then clearly $\cos{x} + \cos{rx}$ is bounded by 0?

Comment: I don't really understand why the value $x=\pi$ is relevant (yes, it can be between -2 and 0). Note we minimize over all x first, and then try to find the maximizer over $r$. Perhaps you misunderstood the question?

Comment: hi.  can you post the results of your numerical scan?

Comment: I tried to, but I don't have high enough reputation... Try to upvote me, and maybe this will help ;) In the meanwhile, I've put it on my facebook post.

Comment: Daniel Soudry, $x = \pi$ is relevant precisely because once you fix $r$ you are minimizing the function over $x$. Since $\cos{\pi} = -1$ this means that in order to achieve a function value of 2, $\cos{r \pi}$ would have to achieve a value of 3, which is clearly impossible. If you visualize this function, essentially you are overlaying a denser cosine curve on top of a cosine curve. I think the optimal solution is 0 with r = any even number.

Comment: But I didn't say that the maximum of the function is 2. Only that the maximum is obtained at r=2.

Comment: Ah sorry then misread.

Comment: Apologies, there was an issue with the previous parameter scan: previously, when scanning over $r=$1:dr:10, I only checked over $x \in [0,2\pi]$. However, I should have checked over $x \in [0,\frac{2}{dr}\pi]$, since $\frac{2}{dr}\pi$ can be the (longest) joint period for both cosines. This is now corrected. As you can see, the main result hold, but the overall picture becomes more complicated...

Comment: Solution here:
http://mathoverflow.net/a/209109/44790

Comment: So you don't need an answer?

Comment: If you have a better answer (simpler, or also a solution the bonus problem), I would be most grateful.